# python pandas: conditionnaly delete first row of each group

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.19.2

I have a DataFrame such as this one:

```
   tid                datetime  event  data
0    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.864  START   NaN
1    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.931    END   NaN
2    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.935  START   NaN
3    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.939    END   NaN
4    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.940    END   NaN
5    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.941  START   NaN
6    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.945    END   NaN
7    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.947  START   NaN
8    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.955  START   NaN
```

which contains start dates and end dates for transaction occuring inside threads (tid is the thread id). Sadly, the transaction themselves do not have an unique ID. So I need to group those rows by *tid*, order them by date, then take the lines 2 by 2, in order to have 1 START and 1 END for each transaction.

My current problem is that my initial dataframe may miss the first START event for each thread (in my above example, the line with index 3 is an END event with no previous START). I need to remove those END lines, but I don't know how to do that.
Same problem for the last START lines that do not have a matching END line.

**Sample Input**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''tid;datetime;event
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.864;START
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.931;END
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.935;START
1;2017-03-22 10:59:59.939;END
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.940;END
1;2017-03-22 10:59:59.941;START
1;2017-03-22 10:59:59.945;END
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.947;START
1;2017-03-22 10:59:59.955;START'''), sep=';', parse_dates=['datetime'])
```

**Expected output**

Same dataframe but with the line #2 dropped, because it is the first line for Tid 1 and is not a START event:

```
   tid                datetime  event
0    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.864  START
1    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.931    END
3    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.933  START
4    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.945    END
5    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.947  START
6    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.955    END
```

BTW, bonus points if you end up with something like:

```
   tid          start_datetime           stop_datetime
0    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.864 2017-03-22 10:59:59.931
1    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.933 2017-03-22 10:59:59.945
2    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.947 2017-03-22 10:59:59.955
```

**What I have tried**

`df.sort(['tid', 'datetime']).groupby('tid').first().event == 'END'` does not contain the initial index from my dataframe, so I cannot use it to drop the lines. (or, if I can, it is not obvious how to do that)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is (We can tidy up the custom function to handle more diverse inputs, but this works for the sample input.):

```
df = df.assign(group=(df.tid.diff().fillna(0) != 0).cumsum())

def myTwo(x):
    starttime = x.query('event == "START"')['datetime'].min()
    endtime = x.query('event == "END"')['datetime'].max()
    tid = x.tid.max()
    return pd.Series({'tid':tid,'start_datetime':starttime,'end_datetime':endtime})

print(df.groupby('group').apply(myTwo)[['tid','start_datetime','end_datetime']])
```

Output:

```
       tid              start_datetime                end_datetime
group                                                             
0        0  2017-03-22 10:59:59.864000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.931000
1        1  2017-03-22 10:59:59.933000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.945000
2        0  2017-03-22 10:59:59.947000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.955000
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still checking the docs to understand your answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for creating unique `Series` for grouping and then use custom function where select by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html), last reorder columns by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
a = (df.tid != df.tid.shift()).cumsum()

def f(x):
    start = x.query('event == "START"')['datetime'].iat[0]
    end = x.query('event == "END"')['datetime'].iat[-1]
    tid = x.tid.iat[0]
    return pd.Series({'tid':tid,'start_datetime':start,'end_datetime':end})

print(df.groupby(a, as_index=False).apply(f)
        .reindex_axis(['tid','start_datetime','end_datetime'], 1))

   tid              start_datetime                end_datetime
0    0  2017-03-22 10:59:59.864000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.931000
1    1  2017-03-22 10:59:59.933000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.945000
2    0  2017-03-22 10:59:59.947000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.955000
```

Another solution with `boolean indexing` instead `query` (maybe faster, `query` is better in larger `df`):

```
a = (df.tid != df.tid.shift()).cumsum()

def f(x):
    start = x.loc[df.event == "START", 'datetime'].iat[0]
    end = x.loc[df.event == "END", 'datetime'].iat[-1]

    tid = x.tid.iat[0]
    return pd.Series({'tid':tid,'start_datetime':start,'end_datetime':end})

print(df.groupby(a, as_index=False).apply(f)
        .reindex_axis(['tid','start_datetime','end_datetime'], 1))
   tid              start_datetime                end_datetime
0    0  2017-03-22 10:59:59.864000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.931000
1    1  2017-03-22 10:59:59.933000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.945000
2    0  2017-03-22 10:59:59.947000  2017-03-22 10:59:59.955000
```

Comment: :) I like your answer better. 'shift' cumsum.

Comment: @ScottBoston - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I will adapt and test ASAP with my real dataframe which is a bit more complex than the input I posted here. I am not sure what `(df.tid != df.tid.shift()).cumsum()` is supposed to do ? (looking at the docs right now)

Comment: I tested and I'm not sure that works as needed. What happens when my initial dataframe contains 4 or more consecutives lines for the same tid ? (that happens when 2 consecutive events are going to the same thread) If I understand well, only the first and last lines are considered for start_date and end_date, so the lines in the middle will be ignored.

Comment: @Guillaume - Do you think all values of `tid` in sample are `0` ? Or something else?

Comment: In my sample I have only 2 threads, `0` and `1`, but IRL I have 16 differents threads. Events for each thread are completely asynchronous. Sometimes 1 thread can handle multiples consecutives requests while the others stay idle. I updated my sample to reflect those cases.

Comment: Hmmm, if `tid` is very asynchronous and is possible something like `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''tid;datetime;event
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.864;START
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.931;END
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.935;START
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.939;END
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.940;END
1;2017-03-22 10:59:59.941;START
1;2017-03-22 10:59:59.945;END
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.947;START
0;2017-03-22 10:59:59.955;START'''), sep=';', parse_dates=['datetime'])` ? What is then desired output?

Comment: Sorry if my input wasn't clear enough. Each thread (identified by `tid`) can handle only 1 transaction at a time. In your sample you have a transaction ending in thread 0 after another transaction has been processed. So that is impossible.  You then have 2 transactions starting consecutively while the first one is finished. So, for a given thread, there should always be 1 START then 1 END every other line. The only difficulty is that my logs may not contain the leading START line or the trailing END line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, with a `groupby()` strategy based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23277988/2799941):

```
# make boolean mask to check for valid event entries
def valid_event(x):
    if x.name:
        return df.loc[x.name-1,'event']==x.event
    return False
mask = df.apply(check_event, axis='columns')

# subset with mask
df = (df.loc[~mask]
        .groupby(np.arange(len(df2))//2) # groupby every 2 rows
        .agg({'tid':{'tid':'first'},
              'datetime':{'start_datetime':'min',
                          'stop_datetime':'max'}
             })
      )

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel() # drop multi-index cols

print(df)

   tid          start_datetime           stop_datetime
0    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.864 2017-03-22 10:59:59.931
1    1 2017-03-22 10:59:59.933 2017-03-22 10:59:59.945
2    0 2017-03-22 10:59:59.947 2017-03-22 10:59:59.955
```

Comment: Thank you for this, especially the `.groupby(np.arange(len(df2))//2)` part. Combined with other responses, I was able to solve my problem :) see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to partially solve my problem this way:

```
# order events by thread id and datetime
df = df.sort_values(['tid', 'datetime']).reset_index(drop=True)
# then group by tid
for tid, group in df.groupby('tid'):
     # for each group, drop the first line if it is a END event
     head = group.head(1).iloc[0]
     if head.status == 'END':
         df.drop(head.name, inplace=True)
     # and drop the last line if it is a START event
     tail = group.tail(1).iloc[0]
     if tail.status == 'START':
         df.drop(tail.name, inplace=True)

# take lines 2 by 2, that will be a START and an END event, that can be aggregated
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).agg({'Tid': 'first', 'DateTime': {'start': 'min', 'stop': 'max'}})
```